# Generating random functions (as opposed to random numbers)

Tags: python, algorithm, hash, random

I would like to create a function that takes a string and returns a number between 0 and 1. The function should consistently return the same number when given the same string, but other than that the results should have no discernible pattern. The output numbers for any large set of input strings should follow a uniform distribution.

Moreover, I need to generate more than one such function, i.e. when given the string "abc", function A might consistently return 0.593927 while function B consistently returns 0.0162524. I need it to be fast (it's for a numerical simulation), and have reasonably good statistics.

I'm using Python and will settle for answers of the form "here is an easy way to do it using a Python library" or "here is an algorithm that you can implement." If there's no fast way to do it in Python I'll just switch to C instead.

I realise that either of the following two methods will work, but each of them have drawbacks that make me want to look for a more elegant solution.

1. **Store a dictionary**
   I could just calculate a new random number every time I'm given a new string, and store it in a dictionary to be retrieved if I receive the same string again. **However**, my application is likely to generate a lot of strings that only appear once, This will eventually result in having to store a very large dictionary in memory. It also makes repeatability more difficult, since even if I use the same seed, I'll generate a different function if I receive the same strings in a different order. For these reasons, it would be much better to consistently compute the random numbers "on the fly".
2. **Use a hash function**
   I could just call a hash function on the string and then convert the result to a number. The issue of generating multiple functions could be solved by, for example, appending a "seed" string to every input string. **However**, then I'm stuck with trying to find a hash function with the appropriate speed and statistics. Python's built-in hash is fast but implementation-dependent, and I don't know how good the statistics will be since it's not designed for this type of purpose. On the other hand I could use a secure hash algorithm such as md5, which will have good statistics, but this would be too slow for my application. Hash functions aimed at data storage applications are typically much faster than cryptographically secure ones like md5, but they're designed with the aim of avoiding collisions, rather than producing uniformly distributed output, and these aren't necessarily the same in all cases.

**A further note about hash functions**

To illustrate the point that avoiding collisions and producing uniform results are different things, consider the following example using Python's built-in hash function:

```
>>> hash("aaa") % 1000
340
>>> hash("aab") % 1000
343
>>> hash("aac") % 1000
342
>>> hash("aad") % 1000
337
>>> hash("aae") % 1000
336
>>> hash("aaf") % 1000
339
>>> hash("aag") % 1000
338
>>> hash("aah") % 1000
349
>>> hash("aai") % 1000
348
>>> hash("aaj") % 1000
351
>>> hash("aak") % 1000
350
```

There are no collisions in the above output, but they are also clearly not uniformly distributed, since they are all between 336 and 351, and there is also a definite pattern in the third digit. I realise I could probably get better statistics by doing `(hash("aaa")/HASH_MAX)*1000` (assuming I can work out what `HASH_MAX` should be), but this should help to illustrate that the requirements for a good hash function are not the same as the requirements for the function I'm looking for.

**Some relevant information about the problem**

I don't know exactly what the strings are that this algorithm will need to work on, because the strings will be generated by the simulation, but the following are likely to be the case:

1. They will have a very restricted character set (perhaps just 4 or 5 different symbols).
2. There will be a lot of unique or rare strings and a few very common ones, of varying length.
3. There is no upper bound on the lengths of the strings, but short ones are likely to be much more common than long ones. I wouldn't be surprised if I never see one longer than 100 characters, but I don't know for sure. Many of them will just have one to three characters, so it's important that the algorithm is fast for short strings. (But I guess I could use a lookup table for strings less than a certain length.)
4. Typically, the strings will have large substrings in common - often two strings will differ only by a single character appended to the beginning or end. It's important that the algorithm doesn't tend to give similar output values when the strings are similar.

Comment: Definitely use a hash. What is the distribution of the strings?

Comment: Any hash you implement in Python is going to be slower than md5. You'd have to write it into an extension module. Maybe rc4 is good enough for you?

Comment: @JanDvorak the distribution of the strings is hard to predict in advance because it will depend on the dynamics of a very complex simulation. But it will likely contain a lot of unique ones and a few very common ones, of varying lengths.

Comment: @gnibbler I think RC4 is 1-1 encryption, not a hash.

Comment: @gnibbler md5 is an inherently complex algorithm, and there might be cheaper ones that are readily available as Python extensions. RC4 is likely to have patterns to its statistics that will affect my application, as it's designed to be used on long streams, rather than on many short ones with the same key.

Comment: @JanDvorak other relevant aspects of the distribution are (i) the strings will probably have quite a restricted character set, and (ii) the strings will generally have large substrings in common with one another.

Comment: Seems like any hash function, especial a simple (and relatively fast) one, is going to have a pattern that won't meet your distribution requirements.

Comment: @martineau that's not necessarily the case but I agree it's quite likely. That's why I'm looking for an algorithm that's specifically dedicated to this type of task.

Comment: So, (in one line) you want to generate a 1 or 0 from a string, by applying a hash on it? or using a dictionary (not good as many said)?

Comment: Could you consider each string to be the n-bit numerator of a fraction with a denominator of 2**(n+1) bits yielding a rational number with a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: @paddila no, I want a float between 0 and 1, and the function needs to have the property of being uniform, which is not a property of all hash functions.

Comment: @martineau no, because I need the results to be statistically uniform, and my strings will not be uniformly distributed. The hash implementation has to behave, as much as possible, the same as the lookup table one would.

Answer (score 3):

Use a good random number generator and seed it with the string.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'd discounted it earlier on as I was worried it might have bad statistics because random number generators aren't designed to be used that way. But it will definitely be fast and might have better statistics than a fast hash function, so I should probably try it.

Comment: I'm trying this, and it seems to be producing surprisingly good statistics just using Python's built-in random number generator. If I don't come across any problems with the statistics I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'm curious in how you used the string to seed the generator -- how that's done may be a crucial ingredient.

Comment: Python allows any hashable object to be given as a seed, so I assume it takes the (built in) hash and then uses that.

Comment: Python's built-in hash function produces 32-bit values, which may be too many collisions for what you're doing.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. I guess I'll have to use a different random number generator, because I don't think there's any way to give Python's built-in one a seed with more than 32 bits (although its internal state seems to have a lot more, judging from the output of the get_state function). If I can give multiple 32-bit values as a seed, I can just split the string into segments and hash those.

Comment: You might be able to subclass the `random.Random` class and give it a custom `seed()` method that uses the `setstate()` method internally. The source code for the Py 2.7 version is in [Lib/random.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py). The `internalstate` part of the `state` argument to `setstate()` looks like a variable length tuple of unsigned 32-bit `int`s -- so perhaps you could use one of the `hashlib` module's algorithms to get a longer hash value from the string and then use that as the value of the `internalstate` part of the argument in a call to `setstate`().

Comment: Sorry for necro-posting, but I just found in python's `_random` C code that it is not limited with just 32 bits: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/_randommodule.c#l231
It can accept `long` and will then split it into 32-bit chunks.

Comment: So it would be enough to convert a string into its `long` representation. `long` seems virtually unlimited in length, although too large values will take much time for processing.

Comment: Although internal implementation uses at most `N * 32` bits of the long value, where `N` is `624`. I.e. up to `2496` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

There's an algorithm in the section on "hashing strings" in the Wikipedia article on [universal hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

Alternatively, you could just use some built-in hash function; each of your random functions prepends a random (but fixed) prefix to the string before hashing.

Comment: Yes, I said that my question. The issue that avoiding collisions is not the same as producing uniformly distributed output.

Comment: Aaaah, many apologies - I misunderstood your answer earlier because I skimmed over the Wikipedia article you linked to a bit too quickly. I think such a "universal hashing" algorithm is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

[Lookup3](http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup3.c) is reputed to have very good collision properties, which ought to imply uniform distribution of results, and it's also fast.  Should be simple to put this in a Python extension.

More generally, if you find a function that does a good job of minimizing hash table collisions and has the speed properties you need, a final conversion from a 32- or 64-bit integer to float is all that's needed.  There are many sources on the web and elsewhere of string hashing functions.  Check [Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming), for starters.

**Addition**

One other thing that might be worth trying is to encrypt the string first with a fast 1-1 algorithm like RC4 (not secure, but still close enough to pseudorandom) and then run a trivial hash (h = h + a * c[i] + b) over the cipher text.  The RC4 key is the uniquifier.

Comment: I'll check out those links, but I'm not sure that an algorithm that's good at avoiding collisions will also produce uniformly distributed output. Or rather, an algorithm that's perfect at one would also be perfect at the other, but one that's "good enough" for one application will not necessarily be good enough for the other.

Comment: Well, you seem to be ruling out cryptographic hashes.  This would be the "perfect" you describe except that's too slow. I'm pointing out that there is a middle ground between crypto-level statistical purity and trivial hashes that are bound to have problems: it's the lookup3 sort of hash that goes to a lot of trouble to avoid collisions but is still quite fast.

Comment: Sure, absolutely, it's that middle ground that I'm looking for. I'm not ruling anything out, just noting that having reasonable collision avoidance isn't necessarily the same as having reasonably uniform output. I'll have to go through the maths to determine whether lookup3 has good uniformity in addition to good collision avoidance.

Comment: I had another thought and added it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a Fingerprint such as Rabin fingerprinting.
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_%28computing%29).

If you choose a N-bit finger print you just need to divide the result by 2^N.

Fingerprints are a kind of hash functions which are usually very fast to computer (compare to [Cryptographic hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) like MD5) but not good for cryptographic applications (the key value may be recoverable somehow using its fingerprint)

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't heard the term "fingerprint" in this context before.